# Is it okay to read scope variables from the controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

By "is it okay", I'm looking less for opinion and more for solid reason(s) why this should/shouldn't be done.

Example:

```
$scope.myVar = null;
$scope.myFn = function() {
  if ($scope.myVar) return $scope.otherFn();
}
```

It seems that the scope is for exposing data to the view, but now we're checking it as well.

Lastly, whatever the ruling on this, does using the Controller As syntax change things here? While using the scope this way seems inappropriate, it somehow seems okay when referencing `this`.

Again, to avoid this being labeled a 'conversation' question that isn't appropriate for Stack, I'm specifically looking for grounded reasoning why this practice is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's perfectly valid. The scope is there to hold data and functions used by the view, and this data is controlled by the controller. How could the controller control anything without accessing the data?

Comment: I understand that the controller needs to set data for the view to access, and I understand the view reacting to that data. What I'm questioning is the controller reacting to the very data that it's setting for the view.

Comment: The data is modifiable by the view, so obviously, at some point, the controller needs to read it.

Comment: But shouldn't we be persisting data changes to the model, and reading from that instead? Otherwise the model responsibility gets spread to both the view and the controller.

Comment: The data you put in the scope **is** the model. Direct quote from [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#model): *The values that are stored in variables on the scope are referred to as the "model" in the rest of the documentation.*

Comment: Wow, yep, there it is. But I keep reading about controller bloat, and using the controller as the model being the prime culprit, from smart Angular devs all over the web. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Whatever style you use (using `$scope`, or using `this` and controllerAs) doesn't change much: if a controller is bloated, it's bloated. Un-bloating it usually consists in introducing more fine-grained controllers, and/or in delegating to services or other JS objects. I personally prefer using the $scope, because the use of `this`in JavaScript inevitably leads to bugs, in my experience, and to horrible mess such as `var that = this`, which is precisely what the scope allows avoiding.

Comment: Yeah, that's a fun debate - I personally love using actual named controller instances too much to not use Controller As, but yeah, 'this' is a mess. Thanks for your insight on all of this.